# How to find the factors of a given number using a while loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, factors

I'm trying to complete the task at the bottom of this page but it gives me an infinite loop, if I add the tutorial's suggestion to divide the number by the factor  and assign it to the number it doesn't print all the factors of the number, for example, if I enter 20 it will only print 4, 5 (when I add number = number/candidateFactor which I previously added underneath Console.Write(candidateFactor);

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/looping-logical-expression

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Loops
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
                int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Factors: ");
                while (number > 1) // convert this to while
                {
                    int candidateFactor = 2;

                    while (candidateFactor <= number) // convert this to while
                    {
                        candidateFactor++;
                        if (number % candidateFactor == 0) // found a factor
                        {

                            Console.Write(candidateFactor);
                            if (number > 1)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(", ");

                            }
                    // divide number by the factor you found and assign this back to number
                    // print a comma if number is still greater than 1
                }
                // don't forget to increment factor!
            }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never reassign `number`, so it always has the same value.

Comment: Check this line....  // don't forget to increment factor!

Comment: I put candidateFactor++ to increment and if I assign number = number/candidateFactor it doesn't return all the factors.

Comment: You've already got a good answer to your question but I will note that candidateFactor should start at 1. Otherwise you are not showing 1 as a valid factor of the number (which it is).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Factors: ");
if (number > 1) 
{
    int candidateFactor = 2;

    while (candidateFactor <= number)
    {

        if (number % candidateFactor == 0)
        {

            Console.Write(candidateFactor);
            if (candidateFactor != number)
            Console.Write(", ");
            // divide number by the factor you found and assign this back to number
            // print a comma if number is still greater than 1
        }
        // don't forget to increment factor!
        candidateFactor++;
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

You don't need this loop, this can be changed into an if statement:

```
while (number > 1) // convert this to while
{...}
```

This is not necessary as you have already checked for this in your first 'while'. Therefore at this point you should already know that you are dealing with a number that's greater than one.

```
if (number > 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(", ");

}
```

Separator between numbers can be added after each successful candidate in a slightly different way. I've assumed that you would not want one after the last number, that's why this check has been introduced `if (candidateFactor != number)`

Also, you should increment candidate after you made your checks unless you've got a very good reason to increment it at the start of each iteration.

e.g. if your candidates would start at 1

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Factors: ");
if (number > 1) 
{
    int candidateFactor = 1;

    while (candidateFactor <= number)
    {
        candidateFactor++;
        if (number % candidateFactor == 0)
        {

            Console.Write(candidateFactor);
            if (candidateFactor != number)
            Console.Write(", ");
            // divide number by the factor you found and assign this back to number
            // print a comma if number is still greater than 1
    }
        // don't forget to increment factor!

    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ok thanks this makes much more sense now, you're right I should increment after checks and set the initial candidateFactor to 1